# RuntimeError: Error initializing rest store with URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8237': module 'jwt' has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: machine-learning, pip, mlops

The first command `python run_deployment.py --config deploy` runs successfully and suggests that I run the next command- zenml up

`zenml up` generates the following error.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

[image: image 5]

[image: image 6]

[image: image 7]

I was following along with the MLOPs course by Ayush on youtube. Thank you for your help in advance.

I tried

```
1. pip install jwt
2. pip install PyJWT
3. pip uninstall jwt
4. pip install jwt==1.3.0
5. pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall PyJWT 
6. pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall jwt
```